# Group By rows where value equals 0 or non-existent rows in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a simple piece of SQL code where I am trying to get the monthly averages of numbers. But the problem I am running into is if any number within any given month is 0 then the average returned is 0 or if there are any rows that don't exist with any given month then there are no values returned at all for that month. Hopefully, someone can give me some insight as to what I am doing wrong.

GROUP BY 1 = a.metric and GROUP BY 2 = a.report_dt within the subquery

I have tried inserting the missing rows with a value of 0, but as I said it will return the averaged value as 0 as well.

```
SELECT  a.report_dt - INTERVAL 1 DAY AS 'Date',
        a.metric,
        a.num
FROM    (SELECT *
         FROM reporting.tbl_bo_daily_levels b
         WHERE b.report_dt = reporting.func_first_day(b.report_dt)
         AND b.report_dt > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)
         GROUP BY 1,2
    )a;
```

My expected results are to get the average numbers of each month even if there are non-existent rows within the specified date range or even if there zeroes as values.

Comment: Your query makes no sense.  `a` is not defined.  You are using `select *` with `group by`.

Comment: left out the a declaration at the end of the query, and I defined what the group by was in my question.

Comment: . . That doesn't matter.  `select *` with `group by` simply doesn't make sense.  MySQL now treats this as an error (using the default parameters) -- as do all other databases.  It simply makes no sense.  The columns after the first two should be arguments to aggregation functions.

Comment: Oh well it hasn't given me too much trouble on that front and have not received an error yet, but I see your point I can honestly just move the group by's outside the subquery at that point and I would still get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You need a relation of all the months you want to span. This can be made ad hoc with `UNION ALL`. Then left join the data on the months `GROUP BY` the month and the metric and get `avg(num)`.

```
SELECT m.year,
       m.month,
       l.metric,
       coalesce(avg(l.num), 0)
       FROM (SELECT 2017 year,
                    12 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 2018 year,
                    1 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 2018 year,
                    2 month
             ...
             SELECT 2018 year,
                    11 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 2018 year,
                    12 month) months m
            LEFT JOIN reporting.tbl_bo_daily_levels l
                      ON year(l.report_dt) = m.year
                         AND month(l.report_dt) = m.month;
            GROUP BY m.year,
                     m.month,
                     l.metric;
```

(Change the second parameter to coalesce if you want any other number than 0 if there are no numbers for a month. Or don't use `coalesce()` at all if you want `NULL` in such cases.)